# Problem in reusable code to check internet availability in react native

Tags: react-native

I have made a function that checks for internet availability. whenever I call this function it gives me true every time whether the internet is ON or OFF. I want to have one function that contains code to check the internet and I can call it before fetching data from the internet . my code is below.

```
const [campusList, setCampusList]= React.useState([{label:'Select Campus', value:'select campus'}]);

const isConnected =()=>{
        NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
        console.log("Connection type", state.type);
        console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
        if(state.isConnected)
            return true;
        else
        return false;

        });
    }


const loadCampuses = async()=>{
        if(isConnected)
        {
           await fetch(url)
            .then((respons)=>respons.json())
            .then((jsonResponse)=>{
                    jsonResponse.map((data)=>
                    setCampusList(campusList=> [...campusList, {label:data.Text, value:data.Value}])
                   );
            })
            .catch((error)=>console.log(error))
               //.finally(()=>setLoading(false))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch  Returns a Promise that resolves to a NetInfoState object. you need to wait promise to resolve

**try this**

```
const isConnected = sendRequest => {
  NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    if (state.isConnected) {
      sendRequest();
    }
  });
};

const loadCampuses = () => {
  isConnected(async () => {
    await fetch(url)
      .then(respons => respons.json())
      .then(jsonResponse => {
        jsonResponse.map(data =>
          setCampusList(campusList => [
            ...campusList,
            { label: data.Text, value: data.Value },
          ]),
        );
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

oh right, it's a promise, not just a straight return. you need to await for it. You don't need a separate function:

```
    if(await NetInfo.fetch().isConnected)
```

Comment: i had used it if(isConnected()) but still show me true in both cases either internet is ON or OFF.